# Getting the height of custom button the same in border of a circle:

Tags: html, css

I am creating a circle and inside it are two buttons that is 1/3 of the circle

https://codepen.io/bradrar1/pen/ZEYBNpg

The problem is, I can't get the height of the buttons right in order to be perfectly aligned to the parent circle.

HTML:

```
<div class="circle"> 
  <button class="button one"> Play </button>
  <button class="button two"> Pause </button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 145px;
  height: 100px;
/*   I tried adding z-index to hide excess, but it is now unclickable */
/*   z-index: -1;  */
}

.one {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100%;
/*   trying to hide excess, by adding a black border */
/*   border-left: 5px solid black */
}

.two {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 5px;
  border-radius: 0 0 100%;
/*   trying to hide excess, by adding a black border*/
/*   border-right: 5px solid black; */
}
```

I tried fiddling with the height of `.button` but i can't seem to perfectly align it.

I also tried adding borders with different `px` to try to hide the overlapping sides but it is not perfectly hidden.

My final solution is to add `z-index` to `.button` and it works! the only problem is that I can't click the button anymore.

How can I make it perfect? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this: I have added `overflow:hidden` to `.circle` and remove `border-radius`
on buttons

```
.circle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 100px;
}

.one {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10px;
}

.two {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Wow, overflow hidden is the answer after all! thanks man, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the border-radius property from the buttons, and add `overflow:hidden` to the parent div (the circle)

```css
.circle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 145px;
  height: 100px;
/*   I tried adding z-index to hide excess, but it is now unclickable */
/*   z-index: -1;  */
}

.one {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5px;
/*   trying to hide excess, by adding a black border */
/*   border-left: 5px solid black */
}

.two {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 5px;
/*   trying to hide excess, by adding a black border*/
/*   border-right: 5px solid black; */
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"> 
  <button class="button one"> Play </button>
  <button class="button two"> Pause </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of options here. You can try and align them perfectly (by making each button 50% wide of the circle, and matching the border radius), or you can try your initial thinking of hiding them behind the circle with the extra property `pointer-events` on the circle, like this;

```css
.circle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  pointer-events: none; /* the magic sauce */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 100px;
/*   I tried adding z-index to hide excess, but it is now unclickable */
   z-index: -1;  
   pointer-events: all; /* the magic sauce */
}

.one {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 100%;
/*   trying to hide excess, by adding a black border */
/*   border-left: 5px solid black */
}

.two {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 10px;
  border-radius: 0 0 100%;
/*   trying to hide excess, by adding a black border*/
/*   border-right: 5px solid black; */
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"> 
  <button class="button one"> Play </button>
  <button class="button two"> Pause </button>
</div>
```